# What Monsters Drop the Most Gil?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I'm looking for a way to earn gil fast, since the items used to level up monsters get very expensive towards the end. What are some areas that have random encounters where the monsters drop significant (or significantly more than others) amounts of gil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During end-game play, **Yomi** becomes relatively easy to farm (*Archylte Steppes ???AF*). The fight takes less than ten minutes. To reset **Yomi** you need to return to the Historia Crux and reload the zone. Then you need to switch the weather to anything other than **stormy** before changing it back to **stormy**.

**Yomi** yields a guaranteed `20000 CP` and `48000 gil` per win.

This related question - [How Do I Defeat Yomi?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49950/how-do-i-defeat-yomi) - has information on strategies for defating **Yomi**.

Comment: nothing to add to this, tought NO time reversal is needed.

Comment: @Stefto I didn't say *time reversal* I just said to reload the zone. Meaning - exit to Historia Crux and come back into the zone.

Comment: ah sorry 'bout that guess i was half asleep XD